# Как получить исходные данные из 10-й строки файла?

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

При написании консольного приложения на visual-studio, возникла проблема, мне надо получить исходные данные из 10 строки файла text1.txt, для дальнейшего их анализа.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить чайнику, как получить исходные данные из 10-й строки файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
int lineNumber = 10;
ifstream stream("text.txt");
string s;

for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++)
    getline(stream, s);

cout << s;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Все заработало!!!

Comment: @DreamChild, `while( --lineNumber )` 

;-)

Comment: @klopp: ну ладно вам новичков запутывать. Пусть сначала со стандартным циклом поймут.

Comment: А хоть самую малость, ну вот совсем чуть-чуть, самостоятельно базовую документацию или учебники почитать, совсем для начинающих - не?


`if( strstr( s.c_str(), "сс" ) ) { /* есть */ }`

>так как у меня ни как не выходит считать длину строки

Это ж как нужно постараться, чтобы не вышло?

Comment: У вас не выходит опросить длину `std::string`? А как вы пробовали? Неужели `sizeof`?